# How to set up javascript api where security token is in the body

Tags: javascript, api

Here is the code I use for javascript api data extraction for the scenarios that have the authorization code. However, in this new case the security token must be inputted in the body of the response like this:

```
const https = require('https');
jsons = []

var options = {
  hostname: 'api.intercom.io',
  port: 443,
  path: 'https://api.intercom.io/admins',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {"Accept": "application/json", "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8",
            "Authorization": "Bearer XXXX"} // add headers here

 };
```

Here is what the body looks like with the security token.

```
{
    "pickupDate" : "2017-10-12",
    "originSuburb" : "SYDNEY",
    "originState" : "NSW",
    "originPostCode" : "2000",
    "originCountryCode" : "AU",
    "originResidential" : false,
    "freightType" : "PALLETS",
    "tailLiftPickup" : false,
    "tailLiftDelivery" : false,
    "**securityToken**" : "XXXX",
    "insuranceValue" : 250,
    "resultOutput" : "FULL",
    "items" : [
        {
            "length" : 1.2,
            "width" : 1.2,
            "height" : 1.2,
            "weight" : 400,
            "quantity" : 1
        }
        ]
}
```

How do access this API in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you parse the body to an object to get the security token as an object you can then just place it in line with the header using "+obj.obj+".

I made the assumption that you put the "**" around *securityToken* so I removed it from your Token body.

```
const https = require('https');
jsons = []

var options = {
  hostname: 'api.intercom.io',
  port: 443,
  path: 'https://api.intercom.io/admins',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {"Accept": "application/json", "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8",
            "Authorization": "Bearer "+testobj.securityToken+""} // add headers here

 };
```

Token Body:

```
var testobj = {
    "pickupDate" : "2017-10-12",
    "originSuburb" : "SYDNEY",
    "originState" : "NSW",
    "originPostCode" : "2000",
    "originCountryCode" : "AU",
    "originResidential" : false,
    "freightType" : "PALLETS",
    "tailLiftPickup" : false,
    "tailLiftDelivery" : false,
    "securityToken" : "123-xyz-token-me",
    "insuranceValue" : 250,
    "resultOutput" : "FULL",
    "items" : [
        {
            "length" : 1.2,
            "width" : 1.2,
            "height" : 1.2,
            "weight" : 400,
            "quantity" : 1
        }
        ]
};
```